# UK Spouse visa - Do I provide husband's property deeds if I live there?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

Regarding a UK spousal visa, if I live with my husband and he owns the property do I need to provide deeds of the property for supporting documents or is there no need?

Comment: Hi, this question is off topic on this site, because it's about moving country rather than short term travel. However if you ask this question again at [our sister site, Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/), I'll be able to answer it.

Comment: Sorry theres an error...of my typing

Comment: My question really is because me and my husband is travelling to uk for 8 days..and on checklist requirements Home address such as mortgage or tenancy agreement i cant provide them..since my husband owns the property and i live with him only

Comment: He is also eu citizen and we currently live in his country part of eu..do i need to send his deed of sale as my supporting documents?or its unnecessary

Comment: Are you saying its not a visa to move to the UK, but a tourist visa to just visit for a few days with your husband?

Comment: Which visa specifically are you applying for? And what nationalities does your husband hold?

Comment: Yes..just a standard visit visa..but my husband dont need it..only me...so im worried that they will not approved if i didnt provide any documents to support HOME ADDRESS which i have nothing to provide of those examples they gave such as Property deed/mortgage statements/ tenancy agreements or land registration.because my husband owns the apartment where i live its on his name.So how will i support my application?

Comment: Do i need to provide his property deed?since i will be travelling with him and i am living with him?

Comment: @JöåňńæMæ Is your husband coming with you? And are you traveling before October 31st?

Comment: After october 31st it will be this coming november 1..and yes he is coming with me..